# "=Search()" function giving inconsisten results

Tags: excel, vba

I have this formula:

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH(" ?/?/????",C7)=11)=FALSE,"0"&MID(C7,12,2)&"0"&MID(C7,14,6),
IF(ISERR(SEARCH(" ?/??/????",D7)=11)=FALSE,"0"&MID(D7,12,9),
IF(ISERR(SEARCH(" ??/?/????",D7)=11)=FALSE,MID(D7,12,3)&"0"&MID(D7,15,6),
IF(ISERR(SEARCH(" ??/??/????",D7)=11)=FALSE,MID(D7,12,9),1))))
```

On this cell:
    Completed: 2/22/2017 Status: Completed

it returns 02/22/2017 which is correct

On this cell, copied from another program, 
    Completed: 2/22/2017 Status: Completed
It returns 1.

I can't see any difference in the two lines but apparently the formula sees a difference. Let's say the text is in cells A1 and A2.  If in cell A3 I do A1=A2 I get False.  I cannot see the difference.  I even did =trim(clean( . . on both cells but no joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be simpler for you to use the following formula:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,1) + 1,SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,1))-2)
```

The `MID` function takes the text between the first and second space, which in your case is the date data. The `SEARCH` functions look for spaces, in the first case it's the first space. In the second case it's the first space after the first space; in the real world this is the second space!

Comment: that gives me the date all right but I need to have it in the mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: @aoswald, either format the cell as a date or wrap that formula in `=TEXT( *formula above*, "mm/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: turns out that space between the colon and the first digit of the date is not a space.  It's a nonbreaking space.  If you past it into Word and turn on the fomatting marks, it looks like a degree sign.  Search wont find " " because it doesn't exist.  Any idea how to look for a non breaking space.  I think it is chr(160)

Comment: @aoswald you could just search for the colon + 1 character, and search for a colon - 7 characters (" Status") instead...

Comment: figured it out.  did a =substitute char(160) for char(32) first then did the formula.  Works great now everytime.

Comment: @aoswald glad to hear it!